# Summing result sets in SQL Server

Tags: sql

Suppose I have table as below:

```
Class  Student  Maths  English
------------------------------------
 1      a        50       60
 1      b        -        60
 2      c        70       50
 2      d        40        -
```

And I need a SQL query to produce this result set:

```
Score        Maths   English  Total
--------------------------------------
 1             50       120     170
 2             110       50     160
Grand Total    160       170    330
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    ISNULL(Class, 'Grand Total') as Score, 
    sum(Maths) as Maths, 
    sum(English) as English,
    sum(Maths) + sum(English) as Total
FROM 
    table 
GROUP BY 
    ISNULL(Class, 'Grand Total')
WITH ROLLUP
```

Note that this is T-SQL syntax, it might need a little tweaking for MySql or Oracle.

Comment: To get grand total you need rollup too

Comment: Thanks cjk. I need T-sql syntax and this is perfect.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT
    Class,
    sum(Maths) as Maths,
    sum(English) as English,
      sum(Maths+English) as Total
FROM
    table
Group by
    Class with Rollup
```

Answer (score 2):

[sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7f1f7/10)

I've used a union which doesn't look so elegant

```
create table the_table 
(
  class int,
  student varchar(5),
  maths int,
  english int,
)
insert into the_table
values
( 1, 'a', 50, 60),
( 1, 'b', 0, 60),
( 2, 'c', 70, 50),
( 2, 'd', 40, 0)

select 
  [class] = convert(varchar(50),class)  
  , sum(maths) maths
  , sum(english) english
  , sum(maths + english) total
from the_table
group by
  class
union
select 
  [class] = 'Grand Total'
  , sum(maths) maths
  , sum(english) english
  , sum(maths + english) total
from the_table
```